# Unable to open SAS EG Project

Tags: sas

I can't open my SAS EG Project with the error message :
**"Unable to open file ...abc.egp as valid project file"**

This is happen because when my hard disk is full and I was trying to save the project, so it wouldn't let EG to finish writing the project changes.
I've tried to clear the history but no luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your SAS EG file might be irreversibly corrupt, so the focus is then on recovery of the file or its content.
If your disk drive is NTFS based, you might be able to recover the file. Check for previous versions in the file properties. 
Also, what was the structure of your file inside? If it was a code driven program, then you can make a copy of the file, change extension to "zip" and then unzip the file or look inside for its contents. SAS EG projects are just ZIP archives with XML maps and related SAS code. 
The last option is to see if you have logging enabled in your SAS EG. If you do, then all the code you run on that date would be available in your logs, so you can recover the code from the logs.

Regards,
Vasilij